# store windows directory in MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to store windows directory structure for my upload position.

Upload directory is: `C:\wamp\www\sites\uploads\temp\\`

But when in saved it in Mysql table

```
upload varchar(100) // column
```

all I receive is:

```
C:wampwwwsitesuploadstemp\
```

How can i make it work ?

Comment: Please post the *generated* javascript.

Comment: I'd say you've got a syntax error.....look at your generated source

Comment: @IgorDymov - JavaScript will never see `site_url('/client/')` because PHP should process it into a string before JavaScript ever sees it.

Comment: @Adam: ah, thought it was pure JS

Comment: i edited the question completing your requirement please help me

Comment: Try enclosing your locat variable in double quotes...ie: `locat = 'http://localhost/sites/public_html/site/client/'+play_data+'.pdf';` replaced with: `locat = "<?php echo site_url('/client/'); ?>"+"/"+play_data+".pdf";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try enclosing your locat variable in double quotes...ie:

`locat = '<?php echo site_url('/client/'); ?>'+'/'+play_data+'.pdf';`

replaced with:

`locat = "<?php echo site_url('/client/'); ?>"+"/"+play_data+".pdf";`

Answer (score 1):

In this code

```
play_data = 'resume;
locat = 'http://localhost/sites/public_html/site/client/'+play_data+'.pdf'; //error in this line
alert(locat);
```

You didn't delimit the first string correctly, you're missing the second quotation. This will generate an error in the line you are seeing it in because JS thinks that the first quote (before http) is actually the CLOSING quote from the line before.

It should be

```
play_data = 'resume';
locat = 'http://localhost/sites/public_html/site/client/' + play_data + '.pdf';
alert(locat);
```

Comment: sorry that was a typo. thank by the way.. but problem its still the same

Answer (score 0):

Your echoed values from PHP are being interpreted as provided and breaking your string building attempt. You've likely generated a PHP error, and that error message is being put in place of the code you were expecting.

It would probably be something like: `lolcat = 'oh no there's an error here: blah blah blah'+'/'+play_data....`

Nobody can help you fully, because you haven't posted the actual JavaScript that is being run, or the PHP required to generate that page.

Comment: oops. Justin E just figured it out.

Comment: ... that doesn't help you. You're still prone to the same issue just with a different char.